# Web & mobile cross platform tests by merging react-testing-library with react-native-testing-library

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library, react-native-web, react-native-testing-library

I tried to merge both libraries for cross platform tests when using react-native-web, by resolving file extensions by platform so I can write 1 test for both web and mobile.

It works for the most part, but as my app grew some tests became flaky.  Usually I would find async issues, where a test would pass on web environment, but hang on mobile, or vice versa.  I'm setting up a new cross platform project and I'm wondering has anyone had any long term success with this approach?  Or is the most solid approach today to write 2 tests for mobile / web.  Or are there other tools out there?

Example of the apporach:

`test-utils/index.web.js`

```js
export * from @testing-library/react;
```

`test-utils/index.js`

```js
export * from @testing-library/react-native;
```

`App.test.jsx`

```js
import { render, waitFor } from './test-utils'

describe('Initial test', () => {
  test('App should render', async () => {
    const { findByTestId } = render(Component)
    const someViewInMyApp = findByTestId('some-id')
    waitFor(() => expect(someViewInMyApp).toBeTruthy())
  })
})
```

There is more to it than this, there needed to be some wrappers around some apis, such as events, render methods to wrap with Providers or Route / Screen for navigation etc..

For example:

`test-utils/events.web.js`

```js
import { fireEvent } from ‘@testing-library/react’

export const fireChangeText = (input, value) =>
  fireEvent.change(input, { target: { value } })
```

`test-utils/events.js`

```js
import { fireEvent } from ‘@testing-library/react-native’

export const fireChangeText = (input, text) =>
  fireEvent(input, ‘onChangeText’, text)
```

`some.test.jsx`

```js
import { fireChangeText } from './test-utils/events'
```